# MacBook goes to sleep when I keep a bluetooth speaker on top of it

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

This is kind of a weird question. Since the last year, I have observed multiple times that when I keep my bluetooth speaker on top of my mac, near the trackpad, it suddenly turns off and goes to sleep.

This happens quite frequently but not always.

I am using MacBook Pro 2012 mid and my bluetooth speaker is beetel s2. Also I connect my speaker to mac with aux cable and not bluetooth (sound flickers in case of bluetooth connection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MacBook detects your lid being closed with a magnet. Speakers also have a magnet, [thats how they work](https://blog.landr.com/how-do-speakers-work/).

When you put your speaker on your Mac, it "thinks" the lid was being closed and goes to sleep.